# ERROR:- 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: java, ant, h2

I have tried to run the Activiti BPM tool under ANT but i am getting the following error :-
**ERROR:- 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command**; when i tried to start a demo application using CMD command line under windows 7 i got the following error:-

```
C:\activiti-5.10\activiti-5.10\setup>ant demo.start
    Buildfile: C:\activiti-5.10\activiti-5.10\setup\build.xml

    demo.install:

    internal.cfg.create:
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\activiti-5.10\activiti-5.10\setup\build\activit
i-cfg
      [zip] Building zip: C:\activiti-5.10\activiti-5.10\setup\build\activiti-cf
g.jar
     [echo] copying configuration to ../workspace/activiti-engine-examples/src/m
ain/config
    [unzip] Expanding: C:\activiti-5.10\activiti-5.10\setup\build\activiti-cfg.j
ar into C:\activiti-5.10\activiti-5.10\workspace\activiti-engine-examples\src\ma
in\config

internal.classpath.libs:

internal.taskdef.launch:

h2.start:
     [echo] starting H2 database...
   [launch] launching cmd 'C:\activiti-5.10\activiti-5.10\apps\h2\h2.start.bat '
 in dir 'C:\activiti-5.10\activiti-5.10\apps\h2'
   [launch] waiting for launch completion msg 'TCP server running'...
   [launch]   'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
   [launch]   operable program or batch file.
   [launch] launched process completed
     [echo] H2 database started

tomcat.start:
   [launch] launching cmd 'C:\activiti-5.10\activiti-5.10\apps\apache-tomcat-6.0
.32\bin\startup.bat ' in dir 'C:\activiti-5.10\activiti-5.10\apps\apache-tomcat-
6.0.32\bin'
   [launch] waiting for launch completion msg 'Using CLASSPATH:'...
   [launch]   Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\activiti-5.10\activiti-5.10\apps\apache
-tomcat-6.0.32"
   [launch]   Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\activiti-5.10\activiti-5.10\apps\apache
-tomcat-6.0.32"
   [launch]   Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\activiti-5.10\activiti-5.10\apps\apache
-tomcat-6.0.32\temp"
   [launch]   Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06"
   [launch]   Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\activiti-5.10\activiti-5.10\apps\apache
-tomcat-6.0.32\bin\bootstrap.jar"

explorer.browser.open:

demo.start:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 5 seconds
```

Does anyone know what is going wrong ?
BR

Comment: Try adding _C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\bin_ to your PATH

Comment: great seems to solve thE problem .. but why i should specify this PATH

Comment: I've posted the answer below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\bin` to your PATH.

The reason is that the batch file `C:\activiti-5.10\activiti-5.10\apps\h2\h2.start.bat` has a raw `java` command which relies on `java.exe` being on the PATH.

Answer (score 4):

> ERROR:- 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command;

This means that `java.exe` is not part of your `PATH`.
Add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to your `PATH` where `JAVA_HOME` is your installation directory for java

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. For some reason the java JDK was installed correctly on C:\Program Files (x86)\Java **BUT** in the path it was set to C:\Program Files\Java ... once I corrected the path variable it solved this issue.

Also, watch out if you have Jenkins and Java using the same port number this can cause the appearance that everything is ok by you will need to have them use separate port numbers. To check for this stop Jenkins if it is running as a service and then restart Tomcat